# what is the meaning of 'Likelier than not'

Tags: phrases, expressions

I know what 'likely' means, but the expression 'Likelier than not' is strange to me!

Comment: It just means "probably" ...

Comment: @Hellion you've downvoted, so I want to delete my question, but StackExchange doesn't let me do so, what should I do?

Comment: @pia I have not downvoted, someone else must have done that.  (Though I did cast a close vote to suggest that you might have better results on the [ell.se] website.)  However, because the question has been answered and the answer has a positive score, you are not allowed to delete it.  See [this question & answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255012/how-to-delete-an-answered-question/255013#255013) on Meta Stack Overflow for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematical terms, it means that the chance for something to occur is more than 50%.
This is expressed by saying that it is likelier (*more likely*) [to happen] than [it is to] not [happen].   There could be a 51% chance of it happening (and therefore a 49% chance that it would not happen), or a 99% chance of happening (and 1% of not happening), or anywhere in between, as long as the percentage chance of happening is greater than the chance of not happening.

(If there is a 50/50 situation, the expression to use would be "as likely as not".)

Of course, people rarely have an actual ratio in mind, and may often say this even if they have no idea how likely something is.

Comment: In general we speak without a lot of precision in English, at least not mathematical precision. I doubt most speakers have precise ratios in mind when using such terms."As likely as not" means roughly equal probabilities, but the phrase is used much of the time to allow wiggle room.

Comment: @Robusto very true.

Comment: On the other hand, I like @Hellion's logical analysis of the phrase, because it explains how people came up with it in the first place.

Comment: @Andy: I think you're putting the cart before the horse. As likely as not the precise analysis came after the expression.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said that it's likelier than not that they say it even if they have no idea how likely it is.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange to me too. I would have used ***more likely*** instead of ***likelier*** - and I think I am not the only one:

[image]

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=likelier%2Cmore%20likely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clikelier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20likely%3B%2Cc0)